# Excel, count TOTAL duplicate values across multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

We are looking at counting duplicate values across multiple columns (30 columns).
Basically we had multiple sessions sign ups, we collected emails, we want to know the total of ALL attendees who attended multiples.  Meaning, repeat session attendees.  We just need a total, not per email address.  We need total repeats across all sessions.

I thought a CountIf forumla might work but I have 30 columns. It might still work, I didn't know if there was a range or something else I should use.  I am far from an Excel guru, but work my way around it.

Sample of our data:

| Email - Session 1 | Email - Session 2 | Email - Session 3 | Email - Session 5 | Email- Session 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john.doe@me.com | mac.doe@blah.com | Jane.doe@me.com | sam.smith@me.com | jack.blak@mo.com |
| Jane.doe@me.com | john.doe@me.com | mac.doe@blah.com | john.doe@me.com | sam.smith@me.com |

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMPRODUCT with COUNTIF:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(A2:E3,A2:E3)>1)/(COUNTIF(A2:E3,A2:E3)))
```

[image]

Comment: That looks promising.  So if I possibly understand this A2:E3 would gather the range?  So if II had 30 columns to column AD and the rows could equal up to 40 or so in some columns, it would look like A2:AD40.  Is this correct in my thinking?  Like I said, not greatly versed in the Excel world

Comment: yes, the references should include your full data set.